# how does checksum is used in the adobe air and vista on worklight 5

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using worklight 5. from my understanding worklight creates on build an air package for the adobe air environment.

How does worklight uses the checksum from the life cycle of a request point of view?

Is there a checksum for the vista environment?

Regards,
Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Worklight v5.0.6.x does not use checksum in the Adobe Air and Vista Gadgets environments.
Note: Vista Gadgets environment has been removed in Worklight v6.0

If you have something else in mind, please edit your question and expending on it, as right now it's too broad.